# How to modify literal.id to literal.{xxx}

Tags: pdf, solr, literals

I am trying to modify "literal.id" to "literal.docId", "literal.aa" and so on. because I want to change the uniqueKey like docId or another name to understand easily. the id is too simple. :D
But for this, most documents and web pages I have searched have mentioned "The literal.id={value} param provides the necessary unique id for the document being indexed"

If someone knew how to do it, plz give me some hints, tips or answers.

Thank you.

-Rex-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you upload a pdf to Solr, it populates Solr with

1. values extracted by Tika and mapped to Solr fields: `content` and `author_name` in the schema are filled like this
2. values given as parameters: literal.fieldxy gets mapped to fieldxy in Solr schema

In your case, your solr schema uses a field `id` for uniqueness. Hence the need to specify a `literal.id` for each upload. If you create a core with a different ID scheme, be sure to include a `literal.idfield` for each upload.

Comment: so, in this case, uploading a PDF, the UniqueKey in schema.xml must be "id". I cannot change from "id" to another name like "idfield". Therefore, the uniquekey must be id and literal.id for a pdf and then I can include another name like "idfield" is it right? thank you for your kind answer. -Rex-

Comment: Your solr index needs an ID field like a relational DB needs a primary key. You can set your index to use `idfield` (whether a string or int or other type) as unique index if you so wish. And if you feel that an answer have resolved your query, mark ✓ as accepted